# Lose repeated value inside ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/iudfM57f61VymkJElTpY?p=preview)

I have some cars and available years for them:

- ["Volvo", "VW", "Audi"] --> [2006, 2007, 2008]
- ["Ford", "Honda", "Jaguar"] --> [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011]

Note: **2008 year is repeated**. It's important)

I set 2006 (any year **except 2008**) year for Volvo by default.
Click "Load car 1", then "Load car 2".
You can see 2006 yet. It works.

But change from 2006 to 2008.
Click "Load car 1", then "Load car 2".
2008 is lost. It doesn't work.

Why? What don't I understand? It doesn't matter type of value for SELECT tag (number or string)

---

If I remove

```
//I use length = 0 in ng-disabled to user can't change 'year' while timeout interval
if (main.years) main.years.length = 0;
```

or $timeout it will work.
I tried to use bind. It didn't work.

Thanks.

---

I did simple example. But in my project I have a lot of fields and slow client server. **And** if I choose cars **very quickly**, *data in cars array* and *options in select* are lost

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($timeout) {
  var main = this;

  main.selectCar = selectCar;
  main.models = ["Volvo", "VW", "Audi", "Ford", "Honda", "Jaguar"];
  //main.years = [2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011];
  main.cars = [{
    year: 2006,
    model: "Volvo"
  }, {
    year: 2011,
    model: "Honda"
  }];

  selectCar(main.cars[0]);

  // bind doesn't work too
  function selectCar(car) {
    // I use length = 0 in ng-disabled to user can't change 'year' while timeout interval
    if (main.years) main.years.length = 0; //will work without this line

    main.activeCar = car;
    getDataFromServer('years');

    console.log(main.cars[0].year);
  }

  function getDataFromServer(nameForOptions) {
    // don't think about this logic
    // $q
    $timeout(function() { //will work without $timeout
      var arr;
      if (nameForOptions === 'years') {
        if (["Volvo", "VW", "Audi"].indexOf(main.activeCar.model) > -1) {
          arr = [2006, 2007, 2008];
        } else {
          arr = [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011];
        };
      }

      main[nameForOptions] = arr;
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <br /><br />
  <button ng-click="main.selectCar(main.cars[0])">Load car 1</button>
  <button ng-click="main.selectCar(main.cars[1])">Load car 2</button>
  <br /><br />
  <select id="select_1" ng-model="main.activeCar.model" ng-options="model for model in main.models" ng-disabled="!main.models.length"></select>
  <select id="select_2" ng-model="main.activeCar.year" ng-options="year for year in main.years" ng-disabled="!main.years.length"></select>
  <hr />
  <p>Cars:</p>
  <ol>
    <li ng-repeat="car in main.cars">{{car.model}} - {{car.year}}</li>
  </ol>
</body>
```

Comment: I realize the code is in your plunkr, but it's a good idea to edit the code directly into the question.  That way, when the plunkr disappears (it isn't controlled by SO), the code for this question will remain to help others.

Comment: It's a really bad idea to use timeout and wait for data, better to use a callback function that calls the rest of the code once you get the data. This, not only will solve the issue, but is in general a better practice.

Comment: Amir Talic, thanks.  I think with you. But if I use $q and return deferred.promise this not will solve my issue. It's the same thing in my case. [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iudfM57f61VymkJElTpY?p=preview)

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to do here;  this code is all kinds of mixed up.  Firstly, you are *destroying* the binding when you set `main.years.length = 0;`.  Secondly, it's not really clear why you are trying to use a single array to manage two different values.

Answer (score 0):

Please initialize the activeCar to empty object.
    main.activeCar = {};

Comment: Provided an updated plunker link. Can you give it a try? Somehow it works for me.

Comment: I choose 2008 for Volvo, Choose car 2, then car 1. And see 2006, not 2008.

Comment: Oho miss understood the requirement, here is the updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/SroXTO0KuHE7BpCGSY4A?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this
[plunker fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/md6rja8z4liCPtAdOswR?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($q, $timeout) {
  var main = this;
  main.selectCar = selectCar;
  
  main.models = ["Volvo", "VW", "Audi", "Ford", "Honda", "Jaguar"];

  main.cars = [
    {
      year: 2006,
      model: "Volvo"
    },
    {
      year: 2011,
      model: "Honda"
    }
  ];
  
  selectCar(main.cars[0]);

  function selectCar(car){
    //I use length = 0 in ng-disabled to user can't change 'year' while timeout interval (wait server response)
    if (main.years) main.years.length = 0;
    
    main.activeCar = {};

    getDataFromServer('years', car).then(function(){
      main.activeCar = car;
      console.log(main.cars);
    });
  }
  
  function getDataFromServer(nameForOptions, car){
    //don't think about this function and logic inside it
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    //wait server response
    $timeout(function(){
      var arr;
      if (nameForOptions === 'years') {
        if (["Volvo", "VW", "Audi"].indexOf(car.model) > -1) {
          arr = [2006, 2007, 2008];
        } else {
          arr = [2008, 2009, 2010, 2011];
        };
      }
      
      main[nameForOptions] = arr;
      
      deferred.resolve();
    }, 100);
    
    return deferred.promise;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl as main">
  <br /><br />
  <button ng-click="main.selectCar(main.cars[0])">Load car 1</button>
  <button ng-click="main.selectCar(main.cars[1])">Load car 2</button>
  <br /><br />
  <select id="select_1" ng-model="main.activeCar.model" ng-options="model for model in main.models" ng-disabled="!main.models.length"></select>
  <select id="select_2" ng-model="main.activeCar.year" ng-options="year for year in main.years" ng-disabled="!main.years.length"></select>
  <hr />
  <p>Cars:</p>
  <ol>
    <li ng-repeat="car in main.cars">{{car.model}} - {{car.year}}</li>
  </ol>
</body>
```